# Nested ViewPager not refreshing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**Problem Statement:**

I have an activity on which I have used a view pager and inflated two fragments inside it.

The second fragment inside the view pager must also contain a view pager which has another fragment inside it(If you're wondering why this is a view pager if only a single fragment is required, because that is a configurable component and more fragments might be required inside it).

[First Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAila.png)

[Second Fragment and the sub fragment inside it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCVu8.png)

Now, when we click a button I have to refresh the first and second fragments as well as the sub fragment( in the ViewPager) inside the second fragment.

The issue is that the first and the second fragments are getting updated but the sub fragment that is inside the view pager in the second fragment is not getting refreshed.

This happens after the click of the button:

[First Fragment refreshed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k40Wc.png)

[Second fragment refreshed but the sub fragment did not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Zem.png)

**Tried solutions:**

We tried to debug the code, tried clearing the adapters and the lists. Nothing worked.

Any pointers or suggestions welcome !

Code :

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.admin.myapplication;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GuestListPagerAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        setUpViewPager();
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                adapter.clearFragmentList();
                adapter.addFragment(FirstFragment.newInstance("55"));
                adapter.addFragment(SecondFragment.newInstance("88"));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setUpViewPager() {
        if (null == adapter)
            adapter = new GuestListPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(FirstFragment.newInstance("1"));
        adapter.addFragment(SecondFragment.newInstance("2"));
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public class GuestListPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();

        GuestListPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
        }

        void clearFragmentList(){
            mFragments.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Refresh View Pager"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

SecondFragment.java

```
package com.example.admin.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = SecondFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private String mParam1;

    public SecondFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static SecondFragment newInstance(String param1) {
        SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        Log.d(TAG, "newInstance: 2F");
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: 2F");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv.setText(mParam1);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.sub_view_pager);
        SubListPagerAdapter adapter = new SubListPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.clearFragmentList();

        adapter.addFragment(SubFragment.newInstance(mParam1));
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: 2F");
        return view;
    }

    public class SubListPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();

        SubListPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
        }

        void clearFragmentList(){
            mFragments.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }



        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

    }

}
```

fragment_second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4"
        tools:context=".SecondFragment">



    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:id="@+id/sub_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

SubFragment.java

```
package com.example.admin.myapplication;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class SubFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = SubFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private String mParam1;

    public SubFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static SubFragment newInstance(String param1) {
        SubFragment fragment = new SubFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        if(fragment.getArguments()!=null)
            fragment.getArguments().clear();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        Log.d(TAG, "newInstance: sub");
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: sub");
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub, container, false);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sub_tv);
        tv.setText(mParam1);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: sub");
        return view;
    }


}
```

fragment_sub.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SubFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_tv"
        android:textSize="60dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

FirstFragment.java

```
package com.example.admin.myapplication;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = FirstFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private String mParam1;


    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static FirstFragment newInstance(String param1) {
        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        Log.d(TAG, "newInstance: 1F");
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: 1F");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(mParam1);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: 1F");
        return view;
    }
}
```

fragment_first.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">


    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```